# Octave graphic error with the gnuplot installed(with aqua)

Tags: macos, gnuplot, octave

I installed the Octave in OSX 10.11.1 with Homebrew. And while I running the following code:

```
plot(x,y);
```

It turns out this:

```
gnuplot> set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1"  font "*,6.66667" dashlength 1
                  ^
     line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list

WARNING: Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal.


No output will be generated. Please select a terminal with 'set terminal'.
```

But, actually, I installed the gnuplot with aqua first. And I set the `setenv('GNUTERM','aqua')` in Octave.
while I enter the gnuplot, after typed`set term`  it shows the list with `aqua`.
So, I am confused about the problem. how this aqua does not work?

Comment: Maybe you have two different gnuplot versions installed?

Comment: I did installed another aquaterm separately and installed a gnuplot without aqua. But I uninstalled them all. So, if the case is about the version, how should I clean/reconstruct the link?

Comment: My guess was only, that octave calls a different gnuplot executable than you when you invoke gnuplot via the command line. I don't know how to find out which executable octave uses.